# Why does TypeScript compiler behave differently when function called with an identical object in my example?

Tags: typescript

Code snippet:

```
interface Named {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

const makeFullName = (item: Named) => ({
  ...item,
  fullName: `${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`
})

const me = { firstName: 'alexander', lastName: 'rodin', age: 26 }

makeFullName({ firstName: 'alexander', lastName: 'rodin', age: 26 }) // 1st call error
makeFullName(me) // 2nd call is ok
```

I can't understand why I don't have an error on the second call and have an error on the first call, because I pass an identical object in both cases.

Run in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHJwLYQCbIN4BQyyMwUAzmOlgFzKVSgDmRyANnJdRHQ8wQF8CBBAHsQlZBjgBrCADEArmzbdkAXmQAKYJAx1u2AJQaAfNsLEAdDd0QMAGlYxlqzD2QADACR47GK1IKKncBZF9-Kw4uUM9BI2ExCTApFE08EjIY2mQAcjg2CAAPOBBsaFyHdk4QnNyoUWxQSuQ4Jg8AJgA2ZCECaTklFW4tDKDsj3zCkrKKqujayYamkBa2zp6BBIGFVxGsIyA)

Comment: Its a typings error. If you had defined ```const me: Named = {...}``` you would have gotten an error on the initializer but since you hadn't given it a type it was ok. With the way you defined it now, typescript is okay with coercing ```me``` to fit the function requirement

Comment: Check this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks.